# Retorno JSON do Laravel é assíncrono?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, foreach

Tenho uma API em Laravel, com um método `show(id)` que retorna um `response->json($array)`. Dentro dessa função tenho um `foreach`, o meu problema está no `response` que não aguarda o `foreach` terminar para então retornar o json. Isso está ocasionando falta de dados na view.

O Laravel é assíncrono?

Minha `function` da API esta assim

```
use ...

Class ProcessesController ()
{

   public function show($id){

    $db = DB::connection('pgsql'); 

    //$id = nrprocesso
    $process = $db->table('processo')->where('nrprocesso',$id)
      ->join('viatransporte', 'viatransporte.idviatransporte', '=', 'processo.idviatransporte')
      ->select('processo.*','viatransporte.nmviatransporte')
      ->get();  

    //Esse processo não existe
    if (!$process) {
        return response()-> json([
           'message' => 'Record not found process' // Esse processo não existe
        ], 404);
    }

    $idprocesso = $process[0]->idprocesso;
    $idusuario = $process[0]->idusuario;
    $idpessoacliente = $process[0]->idpessoacliente;

    $events = $db->table('followupprocesso')->where('followupprocesso.idprocesso',$idprocesso)
      ->join('eventos', 'eventos.idevento', '=', 'followupprocesso.idevento')
      ->select('eventos.idevento', 'eventos.nmevento', 'followupprocesso.dtprevisao', 'followupprocesso.dtrealizacao', 'followupprocesso.dtprevisaoinicial', 'followupprocesso.observacao')
      ->get();

    $dicapa = $db->table('dicapa')->where('idprocesso',$idprocesso)
      ->join('pessoa', 'pessoa.idpessoa', '=', 'dicapa.idpessoaexportadorrepasse')
      ->select('dicapa.dtregistrodi', 'dicapa.nrdeclaracaoimportacao', 'pessoa.nmpessoa')
      ->get();

    $user = $db->table('usuario')->select('nmusuario')->where('idusuario',$idusuario)->get();

    $client = $db->table('pessoa')->select('nmpessoa')->where('idpessoa',$idpessoacliente)->get();

   //Alterando key do array events para o nº do evento

   foreach($events as $key => $value) {

       $new_key = $value->idevento;  
       unset($events[$key]);     
       $events[$new_key] = $value;
   }

 //    for($i = 0; $i < count($events); $i ++ ){

//           $value = $events[$i];
//           $new_key = $events[$i]->idevento;  
//           unset($events[$i]);
//           $events[$new_key] = $value;

//    }

    //Retornando resultado das consultas
    $processget = [    
       "remotedb" => [
          "process" => $process[0],
          "events" => $events,
          "contarray" => count($events),
          "di" => $dicapa,
          "user" => $user,
          "client" => $client,
       ],
       "localdb" => []
    ];

    return response()->json($processget);
 }
}
```

O response não está aguardando o `foreach` terminar o loop para então retornar o JSON.

Comment: Pode colocar o trecho de código, ou um exemplo de como está o seu código? assim podemos ajudar mais facilmente

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com o código

Comment: Tem como adicionar o código completo e exemplos de como deveria ser o retorno e como está sendo?

Comment: Não ... tem alguma coisa errada no seu código que talvez está trazendo errado as informações, por favor coloque a classe na integra!

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja nos eventos. Uma coisa é o Json ser assíncrono, outra coisa é o evento. PHP geralmente não tem dessa de assíncrono não, o problema é outra coisa.

Comment: Eu acho que o problema está dentro dentro for, mas sem ver ninguém consegue.saber

Comment: `return response()->json($get)`, faltou o parênteses no `response()`. E se você tiver colocado só um resumo do seu código, coloque tudo. Se não ninguém vai saber exatamente o que tem no seu código.

Comment: coloquei o código real galera...

Comment: Coloquei todo o código, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indentifiquei o problema em

```
foreach($events as $key => $value) {

   $new_key = $value->idevento;  
   unset($events[$key]);     
   $events_2[$new_key] = $value;
}
```

criei um array novo e adicione os novos valores nele, depois exclui esse array $events.

Answer (score 0):

O response do Laravel não é assíncrono, veja se não existe nenhum ponto de saída dentro do foreach que esteja ocasionando isso.

Comment: Identifiquei o problema em,